# react-virtualized CellMeasurer returns undefined getRowHeight

Tags: reactjs, react-virtualized

I'm using the react-virtualized [wizard](https://bvaughn.github.io/react-virtualized/#/wizard) to generate a starting point for what I'm using. Essentially I have only clicked "Will your collection have more than 1 row of data?", which gives you this:

```
<AutoSizer>
  {({ height, width }) => (
    <CellMeasurer
      cellRenderer={yourCellRenderer}
      columnCount={numColumns}
      rowCount={numRows}
      width={width}
    >
      {({ getRowHeight }) => (
        <List
          height={height}
          rowHeight={getRowHeight}
          rowRenderer={({ index, isScrolling }) => collection.getIn([index, "name"])}
          width={width}
        />
      )}
    </CellMeasurer>
  )}
</AutoSizer>
```

However after replacing `cellRenderer` and `rowRenderer` with my own methods, the `getRowHeight` variable comes back as `undefined`. It's a bit murky to me what's going on, but List is throwing an error off the bat because it's not getting anything passed to the rowHeight prop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Wizard page is outdated. It is currently outputting syntax for version 8 and I recently released version 9. Sorry about that. I'll try to get it updated soon.

In the meanwhile you can read about the new `CellMeasurer` [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/blob/master/docs/CellMeasurer.md), specifically learn about how it changed [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/pull/577), and see some example uses [here](https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized/tree/master/source/CellMeasurer).